# How to sort associative array by column that contains previous id value?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array

I have such associative array. The key *prev* contains a value to match the *id* value of the previous item.

When *prev* is *0* then it's the first item.

Correct order should be by index *prev*:

- $data[3]
- $data[1]
- $data[0]
- $data[4]
- $data[2]

but I don't know how to achieve this.

```
$data[0]['id'] = 10;
$data[0]['name'] = 'Zoe';
$data[0]['prev'] = 20;

$data[1]['id'] = 20;
$data[1]['name'] = 'Tom';
$data[1]['prev'] = 40;

$data[2]['id'] = 30;
$data[2]['name'] = 'Andy';
$data[2]['prev'] = 50;

$data[3]['id'] = 40;
$data[3]['name'] = 'Kathy';
$data[3]['prev'] = 0;

$data[4]['id'] = 50;
$data[4]['name'] = 'Barbara';
$data[4]['prev'] = 10;
```

Comment: Correct order should be by "name"?  Why then is "prev=0" the first item?  Should it be ordered by "prev" instead?  Please explain?

Comment: Thanks for fast response. Maybe my explanation was not very well. I need to get array with this order index $data[3], $data[1] , $data[0], $data[4], $data[2] but not sorted manually. There're menu items. Each item has its previous position stored in array. So first will be $data[3] because $data[3]['prev'] has value 0; After that we have $data[1] because of its previous value id is 40 (it's id from here: $data[3]['id'] = 40 which is the first one)

Comment: Could you add that explanation to your question? Also, you might want to remove the part where you say `order should be by 'name'` because that makes it sound like you want it sorted by first initial. That might be confusing for people.

Comment: I edited post. So I need to sort this array by indexes with the same conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
<?php

$data = array();

$data[0]['id'] = 10;
$data[0]['name'] = 'Zoe';
$data[0]['prev'] = 20;

$data[1]['id'] = 20;
$data[1]['name'] = 'Tom';
$data[1]['prev'] = 40;

$data[2]['id'] = 30;
$data[2]['name'] = 'Andy';
$data[2]['prev'] = 50;

$data[3]['id'] = 40;
$data[3]['name'] = 'Kathy';
$data[3]['prev'] = 0;

$data[4]['id'] = 50;
$data[4]['name'] = 'Barbara';
$data[4]['prev'] = 10;

$nextId = 0;
$results = array();

while (count($data) > 0) {
    $matchFound = false;

    foreach ($data as $key=>$val) {
        if ($val['prev'] === $nextId) {
            $results[] = $val;
            $nextId = $val['id'];
            unset($data[$key]);
            $matchFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!$matchFound) break;

}
```

The outer `while` loops checks if the `$data` array still has elements. The inner `for` loop searches for the array with element `'prev'` equal to the `$nextId` that we are looking for (initially set to 0). When it finds it, it assigns the id to `$next`, removes the element from the original array, and adds the element to our sorted array.

Comment: Many thanks. This is exactly what I need :) Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean order by "pre"?  You want PHP's usort() function:

```
<?php

$data = array();

$data[0]['id'] = 10;
$data[0]['name'] = 'Zoe';
$data[0]['prev'] = 20;

$data[1]['id'] = 20;
$data[1]['name'] = 'Tom';
$data[1]['prev'] = 40;

$data[2]['id'] = 30;
$data[2]['name'] = 'Andy';
$data[2]['prev'] = 50;

$data[3]['id'] = 40;
$data[3]['name'] = 'Kathy';
$data[3]['prev'] = 0;

$data[4]['id'] = 50;
$data[4]['name'] = 'Barbara';
$data[4]['prev'] = 10;

function my_order($a,$b) {

   return $a['prev'] > $b['prev'];
}

usort($data, "my_order");

print_r($data); //Kathy, Barbara, Zoe, Tom, Andy
```

Using the function "my_order", which compares $data[$x]['prev'] to $data[$x+1]['prev'], you can yield the results sorted by the "prev" values of the array.

Comment: It looks like the OP meant `'prev'` to be a pointer to the previous `'id'`, not the order number.

Comment: Yes, makes it quite a bit more complex, a la your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)'s `usort` function to do so. It takes an array as the first parameter and then a comparison function as the second. From the documentation:

```
function cmp($a, $b){
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

usort($a, "cmp");
```

The comparison function returns 0 if they're equivalent, -1 if `a` comes before `b`, and 1 if `b` comes before `a`. You can order it however you like.
For you, it could look like:

```
function cmp($a, $b){
    if ($a['prev'] == $b['prev']) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a['prev'] < $b['prev']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($data, "cmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this hope it helps you

```
$data = array();
$data[0]['id'] = 10;
$data[0]['name'] = 'Zoe';
$data[0]['prev'] = 20;

$data[1]['id'] = 20;
$data[1]['name'] = 'Tom';
$data[1]['prev'] = 40;

$data[2]['id'] = 30;
$data[2]['name'] = 'Andy';
$data[2]['prev'] = 50;

$data[3]['id'] = 40;
$data[3]['name'] = 'Kathy';
$data[3]['prev'] = 0; 

$data[4]['id'] = 50;
$data[4]['name'] = 'Barbara';
$data[4]['prev'] = 10;

function sortIt($data) {
 $output = array();
 $key = array_search(0, array_column($data, 'prev'));
 $output[] = $data[$key];
 unset($data[$key]);
 $data = array_combine(
   array_column($data,'prev'),
   $data
 );
 while($data){
   $last = end($output);
   $output[] = $data[$last['id']];
   unset($data[$last['id']]);
 }
 return $output;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r(sortIt($data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get a bit better response time using a hash:

```
foreach($data as $rec) {
    $hash[$rec["prev"]] = $rec;
}
$id = "0";
while (isset($hash[$id])) {
    $result[] = $curr = $hash[$id];
    $id = $curr["id"];
}
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/742570)